# What is the following style of typography called?

Tags: typography, style-identification

I came across this recently where, IIUC, the lowercase was superscript while the uppercase was normal or subscript.

What is this style called?

[image: What is this style called]

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regardless of how it is achieved, it is called a "drop cap" or "dropped capital."

Your example without any other context suggests it is a sloppy hack to emulate the effect without having proper control of e.g. baseline offset caused by: ignorance; aesthetic choice; lack of software support; all of the above.

Normally, there would be one drop cap at the start of a paragraph only and usually only one per chapter or section. The fact that there are several in-line suggest an aesthetic choice.

Comment: You'll be relieved to know that I copied and pasted some text superscript and pasted it into a document and the text was typing out in what you see above. That design is not out there in the wild.

Comment: +1 for pointing out it should be sparsely used.  I find that sentence super-hard to read.

Comment: please don't take what I wrote as a complaint. I don't really like it *per se*, but context is everything. I mean, I grew up looking at xeroxed fanzine from the early 70s and believe me, the ones you see online are the good ones people choose to photograph. Evn so, there was a lot of talent and intelligence and it is not so easy to write off some choices as lack of training. And I love sloppy hacks.